# tracing Outgoing SMS

Tags: java, android, sms

Currently i am using ContentObserver on the Uri

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
SMSObserver m_SMSObserver = new SMSObserver(context);
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, m_SMSObserver);
```

in this manner **onChange** method call in both the cases i.e incoming and outgoing sms.
but i need it only outgoing SMS.
and it is noted that

```
 Uri.parse("content://sms/sent")
 Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox")
```

not working
Kindly help me how i can trace the outgoing message.

thankz.

Comment: What language/libraries/framework/hardware are you using?

Comment: I've tagged it android and java as googling the methods android came up for all of them, also makes sens in that it's SMS.

Comment: None of the `content://sms` content providers are part of the Android SDK. Your application will break on existing phones. Your application may break on future Android releases. Please do not use them.

Comment: i am using android 1.1 api 2
kindly tell we what should i do?
my need to trace out outgoing messages.

Comment: You can't; there isn't any more fine-grained change notification. But of course you could query only the outbox URI when you get the update and check yourself what's new to you. Also, upgrade to at least Android 1.5.

Comment: from different form i observe that applying ContentResolver  is only the solution to tacking outgoing message.

Now i am able to read message from  Uri.parse("content://sms/sent").
but not able to put ContentResolver on Uri.parse("content://sms/sent").
i think may be the permission problem but not sure.

Comment: why do you need to trace the outgoing SMS? wouldn't you know where it is going to whom you are sending it to?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for the answer...

I have not figured out the correct URI to scan only the outgoing messages but a good way to distinguish an outgoing from an incoming message is to use the type of the message.

If the type is 2, then it is an outgoing message, and if it is 1, it is an incoming message.

```
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"),
                    null, null, null, null);

int type = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
if(type == 1){
  //Processing the incoming message
}else if(type == 2){
  //Processing the outgoing message
}
```